# Wordpress, echo list of slug terms with custom link

Tags: wordpress, loops, slug

i'm trying to get a list of terms (using CPT UI) with my custom link where the slug is the last part of the custom link.

Example: 
Clients: Term1, Term2, Term3

where each term is a link like:

```
example.com/#term1
example.com/#term2
example.com/#term3
```

So, i have the same custom link structure but only the final slug changes:

```
$servizio = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'servizio');
$servizio = array_values($servizio);
    for($cat_count=0; $cat_count<count($servizio); $cat_count++) {
        echo $servizio[$cat_count]-> slug;
        if ($cat_count<count($servizio)-1){
            echo ', ';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead `foreach` loop, it's a lot easier to iterate in terms.

```
$categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'servizio');
$categories_output = [];

if ($categories) { // Prevent the error #Invalid argument supplied for foreach()# incase the post has no category
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categories_output[] = '<a href='. get_bloginfo('url') . '/#' . $category->slug .'>'. $category->name .'</a>';
    }
}

if ($categories_output) {
    echo implode(', ', $categories_output);
}
```